# How to display uploaded document(.doc,.docx,.pdf,.odf) in document viewer

Tags: python, django

I had upload documents and stored it in database.Now I try to display the document in browser using google document viewer.But It not displayed.In output page having one link while click that link it will download that particular document. I have post that both code and output below.Give me some idea to display the document.

Templates

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/media/{% for detail in profile_detail %}{{ detail.res_act }}{% endfor %}&embedded=true" style="margin:0 auto; width:800px; height:800px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Output

```
Sorry, we were unable to find the document at the original source. Verify that the document still exists.
You can also try to download the original document by clicking here.
```

Comment: I posted another one question.Please share your ideas

Answer (score 3):

`127.0.0.1` is only accessible from your own computer. It cannot be accessed remotely; which is why the Google viewer cannot show your document.